# Android VideoSupportFragment with IMA sdk ads not showing skip button

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-tv, imasdk

I am using the below code in fragement which extend VideoSupportFragment

```
adsLoader = ImaAdsLoader.Builder(requireContext())
        .setAdEventListener(AdsEventListener())
        .build()

    val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(requireContext())
    val mediaSourceFactory: MediaSource.Factory = DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory)
        .setLocalAdInsertionComponents({ adsLoader }, { mPlayerView })

    // Create an ExoPlayer and set it as the player for content and ads.
    mPlayer =
        ExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext())
            .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
            .build()
```

and player code

```
 adsLoader?.setPlayer(mPlayer)

    val tagUrl = "https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dskippablelinear&correlator=4353245"

    // Create the MediaItem to play, specifying the content URI and ad tag URI.
    val contentUri = Uri.parse(video.videoUrl)
    val adTagUri = Uri.parse(tagUrl)
    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(contentUri)
        .setAdsConfiguration(MediaItem.AdsConfiguration.Builder(adTagUri).build())
        .build()

    // Prepare the content and ad to be played with the SimpleExoPlayer.
    mPlayer?.addListener(mEventListener)
    mPlayer?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    mPlayer?.prepare()
```

It's working fine, but not showing the skip countdown as well as the skip button.
I have tried and tested 4-5 skippable ads, but no one is displaying the skip button
Working on Android TV using Leanback Lib.